# Is there an open-source material database management GUI?

Tags: software-recommendation

Does somebody know an open-source GUI for the management of a small material database?

I have a spreadsheet with some materials in it. Each materials has some temperature-dependent properties like this:

[image]

.

The problem is that some parameters are a function of temperature, and entering equations in cells is a little error-prone. Also I would like to switch between units (imperial, SI) sometimes.

I thought about writing a small GUI for this (perhaps in Python or a Jupiter notebook, ideas welcome :) ), but before I reinvent the wheel, I wanted to ask you guys if there is already something like this.

Cheers,

Ken